# Hive - (Hue) Split string into multiple columns from 1 single string

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue

I am trying to split the string data below column l_ipaddress with "Get/HTTP/1.1"200 1000
to be in the 3rd column.

[image]

Original data was in this form in one column

[image]

This is the script :

```
SELECT SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\\]'')[0] as l_ip,
SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\\ " "')[1] as l_ipaddress,
SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\t')[2] as l_url

FROM web.tempweblog;
```

I have tried a few number of ways like inputting \s, " " since got space. But it doesnt work.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I would try but you posted pictures instead of text and it complicates things a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe:

```sql
SELECT 
    SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\\]')[0] as l_ip,
    SPLIT(SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\\]')[1], '"')[0] as l_ipaddress,
    concat(SPLIT(SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\\]'')[1], '"')[1],SPLIT(SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'\\]')[1], '"')[2]) as l_url
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to run but encountered this error : "error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 12:31 mismatched input ']' expecting ) near ''\\]'')[0] as l_ip, SPLIT(SPLIT(tempweblog.l_ip,'' in function specification" . hmm..

Comment: This one I copied from you (it's first column ```split``` as per your code) - I didn't test it, I assumed it worked for you. If you share revised ```l_ip``` I can insert it in my code

Comment: Hi, I did not do any change at the l_ip. I tried to run again the code but got the same error. Did try to change the [0] as i_ipaddress to [1], but doesnt work. hmm..

Comment: I think it was duplicated single quote character- could you check now

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to help, managed to get it sort out by using substring on the [2019-xxx} , then follow by split.